# compile error, too large integer. CreditCardAnalysis.Java

Tags: java, methods, static-methods, credit-card

I'm struggling to figure out what the compile/syntax error is in my code.

```
public class CreditCardValidation {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        System.out.print(prefixMatched(4388576018402626, 4388));

    }

    /*
    Return the number of digits in d
    */

    public static int getSize(long d) {

        int size = 0 ;

        while( d > 0 ) {
            d = d / 10 ;
            size = size + 1 ;       
        }
        return size ;
    }

    /*
    Return the first k number of digits from number. If the number of digits in number is 
    less than k, return the number.
    */

    public static long getPrefix(long n, int k) {

        int f = getSize(n)-k;

        long prefix = n/((int)(Math.pow(10, f)));

        return prefix;
        }

    /*
    Return true if the digit d is a prefix for number.
    */

    public static boolean prefixMatched( long number, int d ) {

        if ( d == getPrefix(number, 4))

            return true ;
        else
            return false ;

        }

    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to call prefixMatched to check whether the credit card number meets the requiremen; if digit d is a prefix for number. However, the only thing I get back from the compiler is:

```
"CreditCardValidation.java:6: integer number too large: 4388576018402626
        System.out.print(prefixMatched(4388576018402626, 4388));


                               ^"
```

I'm sorry if my question is too vauge, this is my first post.

Comment: have you tried writing 4388576018402626L

Comment: Its worth adding that you're using a number to store a credit card "number", you don't add, subtract, divide or multiply credit card numbers, so its not a numner, its a "word"; so store it as a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are specifying an integer literal `4388576018402626` and that number is larger than [the maximum integer, `2147483647`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE).

You are attempting to pass it to a method that takes a `long`, so make it a `long` literal by appending `L`:

```
System.out.print(prefixMatched(4388576018402626L, 4388));
```

The [JLS specifies this behavior in Section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

and

> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4).

Comment: I see, thank you. If I may ask you another question, why do I get the result as false for the number and d I have provided although it is supposed to be true?

Comment: It's another bug related to an integer being too large.  You get a length of 16 from `getSize`.  Your `f` variable is thus `16 - 4`, or `12`.  The result from `Math.pow(10, f)` is `10^12`, which is too large to fit in an `int`.  The cast to `int` causes overflow and an incorrect `prefix`.  Cast the result of `Math.pow(10, f)` to `long` instead of `int` and you'll get the correct result.

Comment: I appreciate it. Can you see what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to sum every other digit in the card number by doing this:
/*
 Return the sum of the odd-place digits.
 */
 
 public static int sumOfoddPlace(long number)
    {
        int maxDigitLength = 16;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxDigitLength; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                sum = sum + (int)(number % 10);
            }
            break;
        }
        return sum;
All I get it 6, the sum I am looking for is supposed to be 37.
Sorry for asking you so many question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to indicate to the compiler that your constant (the CC number) is a long.  Put an **L** on the end of the constant.
2. It's actually a little easier to treat CC numbers as strings and use charAt(x) to calculate check digits.

Answer (score 0):

add `L` at the end of your literal :

```
4388576018402626L
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Long` instead of  `Integer`

**int:** By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. Static methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.

**long:** The `long` data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 264-1. The unsigned long has a minimum value of 0 and maximum value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int. The [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) class also contains methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned long.

You should use following to avoid `exception`:

```
System.out.print(prefixMatched(4388576018402626L, 4388));
```

The `L` indicates given value is `long`. You can use either `l` or `L` but I prefer to use `L`  because it looks goods while looking code.

**Source:** Oracle Docs.

Comment: `why do I get the result as false for the number`: Because java compiler is thinking as `integer` until and unless appending with either `l` **lower-case l** or **UPPER-CASE L** on the right side of given number.

Answer (score 0):

For this code, I would recommend using `String` instead of dealing with `long` and `int`. It's far easier when trying to match the first four digits, which can be isolated easily using [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29): `(String_name).substring(0,4)` will be return first four digits of the String. This can then be parsed as an `int` using [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), or simply compared to another `String` (if the prefix were a `String` as well).